# Why is my form doing other things than what I told it to do on submit?

Tags: javascript, forms

I've ripped some code from a website and I want to change the action of one of their `input` elements (since it was causing a Server Error). So what I did is change the `action` to `""` and add `onsubmit="myFunction()`". What I have is like

```
<form method="get" name="formname" action="" onsubmit="myFunction()"> .... </form>
```

and

```
function myFunction()
{
    alert("good, my function was called");   
}
```

I've confirmed that when I click enter in the `input`, the `alert` function is called. However, the Sever Error that the form was causing is still happening ***after*** I click ok on the alert.

Any ideas on why this might be? Basically, I'm trying to make `myFunction` be the only thing that happens when the `form` is submitted.

Comment: `return false;` at the end of the function to stop the default action

Comment: First, input fields don't have action attributes, only forms do. Second, if you rip code from other sites without knowing how it works, why do you expect it to work? Third, if a form doesn't have an explicit action set, it defaults to submitting the form back to the page it exists on, so you would need to stop that behavior with a preventDefault() or return false.

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to do `preventDefault()` or `return false` in submit function call, else it will do execute default behavior i.e. submit form.

Either do it like this.

```
function myFunction()
{
    alert("good, my function was called");   
    return false;
}
```

And in calling function use `return myFunction()`.

or use `preventDefault`

Answer (score 0):

You are currently executing the default action. You can prevent that by returning false at the end of your function.